# Dropbox upload file by python error

Tags: python, sdk, dropbox, dropbox-api

I'm trying to upload files list to dropbox, but I get various kinds of errors. I tried this, and tried everything on the net. But I still can't get it work.

```
# Include the Dropbox SDK libraries
from dropbox import rest, session
import webbrowser
import os
import glob
import zipfile
import datetime
from dropbox import client

# Get your app key and secret from the Dropbox developer website

# (app keys defined here)

# ACCESS_TYPE should be 'dropbox' or 'app_folder' as configured for your app
ACCESS_TYPE = 'app_folder'
sess = session.DropboxSession(APP_KEY, APP_SECRET, ACCESS_TYPE)

request_token = sess.obtain_request_token()

url = sess.build_authorize_url(request_token)

file_list = []

#get the date
now = datetime.datetime.now()

def initialize():

    #print "url:", url
    # open a public URL, in this case, the webbrowser docs
    #url = "http://docs.python.org/library/webbrowser.html"
    webbrowser.open(url)
    print "Please click the 'Allow' button to Authorize..."
    print """
    Please select by entering the specific number...
    1 Backup all my files by one by one
    2 Backup specific folder
    3 Backup specific file
    4 Get my account details
    5 About this software
    6 Exit
    """
    try:
        # This will fail if the user didn't visit the above URL and hit 'Allow'
        access_token = sess.obtain_access_token(request_token)
    except:
        print "Error has occured"

def getAccountInfo():
    from dropbox import client
    client = client.DropboxClient(sess)
    account_info_dict = client.account_info()
    print "linked account:"

    for item in account_info_dict:
        if type(account_info_dict[item]) == dict:
           inner_dict = account_info_dict[item]
           for item1 in inner_dict:
               print item1, ":", inner_dict[item1]
        print item, ":", account_info_dict[item]

def getAllFiles():
   for dirname, dirnames, filenames in os.walk('I:/'):
       for subdirname in dirnames:
           print os.path.join(dirname, subdirname)
       for filename in filenames:
           file_name = os.path.join(dirname, filename)
           print file_name
           file_list.append(file_name)
   return file_list

def upload_one_by_one(sess):
   from dropbox import client
   files = getAllFiles()
   client = client.DropboxClient(sess)
   #zip_file_name = now.strftime("%Y%m%d%H%M")+ ".zip"    
   #z = zipfile.ZipFile(zip_file_name, "w")
   for file_item in files:
       #z.write(file_item)
       #f = open(zip_file_name)
       response = client.put_file("test/", file_item)
       print "uploaded:", response
       break


initialize()
#getAccountInfo()
upload_one_by_one(sess)
```

The problem with the client.put_file() argument. I am trying to upload image file in the folder of test. But yet it upload as a text file with path to the image file inside it.

Can't I upload image files to dropbox via dropbox sdk?

Comment: Your dev keys have been removed, but there is no guarantee that google didn't index them.  Best to get new ones.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you didn't open the file to upload, this may work:

```
for file_item in files:
  file = open(file_item)
  response = client.put_file("test/", file)
```

Answer (score 1):

`put_file()` takes either a file-like object or a string that represents the contents of a file.  If you pass in a file name, it won't automatically read in the contents of the file.

Comment: Ok, do you know how to so that? If you know can you please post it here. Thanks for commitment!